# Pagination in Material Component Using Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular2-forms, angular2-services, angular-material2

I am using material component table to show data, and applied sorting, filtering and pagination. Custom filtering work properly, I am following the mention link https://v5.material.angular.io/components/table/overview#pagination but i stucked in pagination below is my code.
Please help where i did mistake.

HTML Code

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">


  <div class="example-header">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput type="text" (keyup)="applyComponent($event.target.value)" placeholder="Component" aria-label="Number" [matAutocomplete]="autocom">
    <mat-autocomplete #autocom="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
        {{ option }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field class="mar-left">
      <input type="text" matInput aria-label="Number" (keyup)="applyRegion($event.target.value)" placeholder="Region" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let region of regions" [value]="region">
            {{ region }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field class="mar-left">
      <input matInput (keyup)="applySector($event.target.value)" placeholder="Sector">
    </mat-form-field>

    <!-- <button mat-raised-button color="primary" class="button">Search</button> -->
  </div>


  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="no">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="customWidthClass"> No. </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let grantsearch; let i = index;" class="customWidthClass"> {{i + 1}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="component">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="customWidth"> Component </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let grantsearch;" class="customWidth"> {{grantsearch.detail.component[0]}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="district">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> District </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let grantsearch;"> {{grantsearch.detail.district[0]}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="organization_name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Organization </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let grantsearch;"> {{grantsearch.detail.organization_name[0]}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="region">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="customWidthRegion"> Region </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let grantsearch;" class="customWidthRegion"> {{grantsearch.detail.region[0]}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>


    <ng-container matColumnDef="sector">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Sector </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let grantsearch;"> {{grantsearch.detail.sector[0]}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="project_title">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Project Title </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let grantsearch;"> {{grantsearch.detail.project_title[0]}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="customWidthAction"> Action </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let grantsearch" class="customWidthAction">
        <i class="material-icons onhover"  (click)="open(content,grantsearch.id)">visibility</i>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>

  <mat-paginator #paginator
                [pageSize]="10"
                [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"
                [showFirstLastButtons]="true">
</mat-paginator>

  <ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">

    <div class="section-1">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Detail</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

          <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Components</th>
                <th scope="col">Organization Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Project Title</th>
                <th colspan="2">Project Description</th>
                <th scope="col">District</th>
                <th scope="col">Region</th>
                <th scope="col">Sector</th>
                <th scope="col">Project start date</th>
                <th scope="col">Project end date</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>{{singleitem[20].component}}</td>
                <td>{{singleitem[20].organization_name}}</td>
                <td>{{singleitem[20].project_title}}</td>
                <td colspan="2">{{singleitem[20].project_description}}</td>
                <td>{{singleitem[20].district}}</td>
                <td>{{singleitem[20].region}}</td>
                <td>{{singleitem[20].sector}}</td>
                <td>{{singleitem[20].project_start_date}}</td>
                <td>{{singleitem[20].project_end_date}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="c('Close click')">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </ng-template>
</div>
```

starter.component.ts

```
 @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.subscription = this.grantsearchservice.getStarterApi()
        .subscribe(
          (grantsearch: any) => {
            this.grantsearchs = grantsearch;
            this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.grantsearchs);
            console.log(this.grantsearchs);
          }
        );
      }

      applyComponent(filterValue: string) {

        this.subscription = this.grantsearchservice.getComponentSearch(filterValue)
        .subscribe(
          (grantsearch: any) => {
            this.grantsearchs = grantsearch;
            this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.grantsearchs);
            console.log(this.grantsearchs);
          }
        );

    }  

    applyRegion(filterValue: string) {
      this.subscription = this.grantsearchservice.getRegionSearch(filterValue)
      .subscribe(
        (grantsearch: any) => {
          this.grantsearchs = grantsearch;
          this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.grantsearchs);
          console.log(this.grantsearchs);
        }
      );
    }

    applySector(filterValue: string) {
      this.subscription = this.grantsearchservice.getSectorSearch(filterValue)
      .subscribe(
        (grantsearch: any) => {
          this.grantsearchs = grantsearch;
          this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.grantsearchs);
          console.log(this.grantsearchs);
        }
      );
    }
    }
```

Comment: It be great if you could create a stackblitz for this much code, but two things. First you should unsubscribe befor subscribing again if your `this.subscription` is set. Second you are overwriting the `this.datasource` in your filters, so the paginator and sort in that object are overriden when applying one of your filters. Might even happen in your ngOnInit, because the API call is asynchronous and may end after your ngAfterViewInit is called and the dataSource is overriden again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this link https://stackblitz.com/angular/epvypoerlaq?file=main.ts hope this help you to resolve this issue.

Comment: I took idea from above given link its very helpful for me but i did write the code my own. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

component.html

```
<mat-paginator #pagination [length]="length" [pageSize]="pageSize" [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions" (page)="pageEvent = dropDown(component.value,region.value,sector.value,$event)"
    #page>
  </mat-paginator>
```

component.ts

```
pageIndex: number = 1;
  pageSize: number = 100;
  pageSizeOptions: number[] = [10, 25, 50, 100];

 setPagination(length, startIndex, pageSize) {
    this.length = length;
    this.pageIndex = startIndex;
    this.pageSize = pageSize;
  }

loadData() {
    this.spinnerService.show();
    this.subscription = this.grantsearchservice.getStarterApi(this.component, this.region, this.sector, this.pageIndex, this.pageSize)
      .subscribe(
        (grantsearch: any) => {
          this.grantsearchs = grantsearch.body;
          this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.grantsearchs);
          this.totalPageSize = grantsearch.headers.get('X-WP-TotalPages');
          this.setPagination(grantsearch.headers.get('x-wp-total'), this.pageIndex, this.pageSize);
          this.spinnerService.hide();
        }
      );
  }

ngOnInit() {
    this.loadData();
  }
```